# loop for the file names

Tags: r, file, loops

I am trying to make a loop through several folders. In each of them I need to change the file name which contains a number equal to i from the loop

But it does not work. 
How should I specify that this "i" in the file name is variable?

```
 for(i in seq(240, 555, 5))
 {
    folder <- "C:/R_Files/test_auto_table_generator/pregnant_3mes_130kv_i"
    list.of.files <- list.files(folder, full.names=T)
    file.rename("C:/R_Files/test_auto_table_generator/pregnant_3mes_130kv_%%i/test_1_DoseDistribution.raw", "130kv_%%i_DoseDistribution.raw")
 }
```

Comment: You need to generate the folder string with `paste`, e.g. `folder <- paste0("C:/R_Files/test_auto_table_generator/pregnant_3mes_130kv_", i)`. Same with the rename.

Answer (score 0):

As your folder structure is not clear, I am assuming you want to do the following:

1. Rename the file `test_1_DoseDistribution.raw` in folders `pregnant_3mes_130kv_n`, where `n` is 240, 245, ... 555.
2. The new filename should be `130kv_240_DoseDistribution.raw`, `130kv_245_DoseDistribution.raw`, and so on, depending on the folder it is in.

Using the good ol' `for` loop:

```
for(i in seq(240, 555, 5)){
  folder.location <- paste0("C:/R_Files/test_auto_table_generator/pregnant_3mes_130kv_", i)
  old.file <- paste0(folder.location, "/test_1_DoseDistribution.raw")
  new.file <- paste0(folder.location, "/130kv_",i, "_DoseDistribution.raw")

  file.rename(old.file, new.file)
}
```

Using `sapply`:

```
sapply(seq(240, 555, 5), function(x) {
        file.rename(
          paste0("C:/R_Files/test_auto_table_generator/pregnant_3mes_130kv_", x, "/test_1_DoseDistribution.raw"), 
          paste0("C:/R_Files/test_auto_table_generator/pregnant_3mes_130kv_", x, "/130kv_", x, "_DoseDistribution.raw")) 
})
```